# How is it possible to modify the whole body part of an xml document loaded in php via simplexml?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Assume the following xml document

```
<technicaldata template="123">

<name>
<![CDATA[Blub1]]>
</name>


<numbers>

<![CDATA[1
2
3
4
5]]>
</numbers>

<shortinfo>

<![CDATA[ha ha ha ha ha ha ha ha.]]>
</shortinfo>

<detailedinfo>

<![CDATA[hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi
hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi
hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi]]>
</detailedinfo>


</technicaldata>
```

Now I load the file via simplexml;

```
$data='test.xml';
$inhalt = simplexml_load_file($datei);
```

But now $inhalt is an object where I can't use e.g. str_ireplace(string remove, string add,$inhalt);
So if I e.g. want to replace something I need to go into every body part of the xml document in order to be able to replace it;

So I do this:

```
$name = $inhalt->name;
$name = str_ireplace(string remove, string add,$name);

$numbers = $inhalt ->numbers;
$numbers = str_ireplace(string remove, string add,$numbers);

$shortinfo=$inhalt ->shortinfo;
str_ireplace(string remove, string add,$shortinfo);

$detailedinfo=$inhalt ->detailedinfo;
str_ireplace(string remove, string add,$detailedinfo);
```

and so on;

So do you have any idea how I can replace something for the whole body part and not just parts of it? So some version of:

```
$inhalt = str_ireplace(string remove, string add,$inhalt);
```

which doesnt't work in this case?

Sorry, I know it sounds totally easy and stupid but I'm a bloody beginner;

Many thanks!! :)

Answer (score 0):

you could loop through all the children of your xml object like this:

```
foreach ($inhalt->children() as $child) {
    $child= str_ireplace(string remove, string add,$child);
}
```

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks this helps a lot! But I have one question left; this operation doesn't overwrite $inhalt and also doesn't create a new object with the corrected content of $inhalt... So how do I get the corrected version out of it?

Comment: you could use `echo $inhalt->asXML();` to output/save XML string with the corrected version.

Comment: I will try... Thanks a lot.. :)

Comment: great, don't forget to set it as the accepted answer (if you think so) :)

Answer (score 0):

This is easier in DOM because you can address and modify the text nodes (including CDATA sections) directly:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/technicaldata/*//text()') as $textNode) {
  $textNode->data = str_replace(['hi', 'ha'], ['foo', 'bar'], $textNode->data);
}

echo $document->saveXml();
```

## The Xpath expression

In the `technicaldata` document element fetch any element node ...

`/technicaldata/*`

... fetch text node (simple text or cdata sections) inside them:

`/technicaldata/*//text()`

Comment: Thanks... It's a littlie confusing because I'm quite bad in this stuff but I'll try.... Thank you so much... :)